# Point domain name to ip adress without any control panel

Tags: nginx, dns, ip-address, vps

I am new to servers. I have a `VPS` with an `ip-address` like `10.10.10.10` and also have a domain for example `myserver.com`. I have no control panel installed on my VPS and I want to point the domain to that ip. I have installed `nginx` and I can access to a simple HTML page which I designed from the web just with `ip-address`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please install DNS Server and configure it such to set a CNAME record in zone file.

```
yum -y install bind bind-utils
```

Comment: Thanks, I have installed `bind9` because my server is `Ubuntu`. [This](https://pastebin.com/eRJTnMvh) is `emadhelmi.com` and [This](https://pastebin.com/XVn9ykPN) is `named.conf.local` in `/etc/bind/`. But when I ping `emadhelmi.com` there is no ping result.

Comment: are you config  nameserver @ns1.emadhelmi.com ?

Comment: Yes, [this](https://ibb.co/iEYjOa) is nameservers on the admin panel of my domain seller.